# Summarize 2darray by index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to sum columns of a 2d array `dat` by row index `idx`. The following example works but is slow for large arrays. Any idea to speed it up?

```
import numpy as np

dat = np.arange(18).reshape(6, 3, order = 'F')
idx = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2])

for i in np.unique(idx):
    print(np.sum(dat[idx==i], axis = 0))
```

**Output**

```
[ 0  6 12]
[ 6 24 42]
[ 9 21 33]
```

Comment: That piece of code does not produce that output....

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed this issue.

Comment: What is generating the `idx` array? Is there a reason that there are repeated indices in the first place?

Comment: Can you give an example for a large array?

Comment: Is the idx array always sorted?

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1**

We can leverage `matrix-multiplication` with [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) -

```
In [56]: mask = idx[:,None] == np.unique(idx)

In [57]: mask.T.dot(dat)
Out[57]: 
array([[ 0,  6, 12],
       [ 6, 24, 42],
       [ 9, 21, 33]])
```

**Approach #2**

For the case with `idx` already sorted, we can use [`np.add.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) -

```
In [52]: p = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,idx[:-1] != idx[1:]])

In [53]: np.add.reduceat(dat, p, axis=0)
Out[53]: 
array([[ 0,  6, 12],
       [ 6, 24, 42],
       [ 9, 21, 33]])
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit faster approach with `set` object and `ndarray.sum()` method:

```
In [216]: for i in set(idx):
     ...:     print(dat[idx == i].sum(axis=0))
     ...:     
[ 0  6 12]
[ 6 24 42]
[ 9 21 33]
```

---

Time execution comparison:

```
In [217]: %timeit for i in np.unique(idx): r = np.sum(dat[idx==i], axis = 0)
109 µs ± 1.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [218]: %timeit for i in set(idx): r = dat[idx == i].sum(axis=0)
71.1 µs ± 1.98 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```